# Samba 4.2 Shadow Copies in Windows 10 - empty list

Tags: linux, samba, zfs

I have a Debian 8 system with Samba 4.2. I'm using ZFS file system for data storage. Windows sharing is working fine, except Windows clients can't see any Shadow Copies snapshots.

My samba config is:

```
[Test]
comment = test
writable = yes
directory mask = 0777
guest ok = Yes
path = /samba/123
create mask = 0666
read only = No
vfs objects = shadow_copy2
shadow: format = auto-%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S--28d
shadow: sort = desc
shadow: snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
```

My snapshot list is:

> zfs list -t snapshot

```
NAME                                     USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/samba/123@GMT-2017.01.06-16.00.00    64K      -    96K  -
tank/samba/123@GMT-2017.01.07-10.00.00    64K      -    96K  -
tank/samba/123@GMT_2017.02.07-14.00.32    64K      -   120K  -
tank/samba/123@GMT_2017.02.07-07.02.04    64K      -   120K  -
```

I can actually cd into .zfs/snapshot and see these snapshots.

I'm trying to check any errors in log:
journalctl -u smbd -f does not see any errors/warning even with debug level = 10.
I even checked client-server communications with Wireshark, and it seems to be OK also:

```
SMB2    178 Ioctl Request FSCTL_GET_SHADOW_COPY_DATA File: test1.txt
SMB2    186 Ioctl Response FSCTL_GET_SHADOW_COPY_DATA File: test1.txt SUCCESS
```

What else can I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it to be sure, however I think you shouldn't add the expiration duration (--28) to the shadow format. Oh, and obviously your format is wrong, you're mixing up the separators, they don't match those you're using for your snapshots. Set it up this way:

```
   shadow: format = auto-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
```

Comment: I have played with settings and finally get ShadowCopies to work. Offender was shadow:format. It looks like he is very picky about snapshots names. My current setup is: Snapshots names: tank/test@2017-02-13_17.00.01--8w And format in SMB.conf is: shadow:format= %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S--8w  Now everything working as expected.

Comment: Update: it seems like shadow_copy2 does not like names like "Docs_pictures" or "Docs pictures" or "Docs-pictures".   "Docs__pictures" seems to work fine.